# Minimal number of points to define a rotated ellipse?

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections, least-squares

What is the minimal number of points $N$ to uniquely define the semi-major axis $a$, the semi-minor axis $b$ and the rotation angle $\omega$ of an ellipse whose the center is known/fixed (this is related to ellipse fitting procedures).

In other words, if we consider that the center is known/fixed, on this image what is the minimal number of blue points I need to compute $a$, $b$ and $\omega$ in a unique way ?
[image: ellipse]

EDIT: and what is the number of points needed when the center of the ellipse is not known ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation of an ellipse is given by
$$ ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f = 0 $$
where $(a,b,c,d,e,f)\in\mathbb{P}^5(\mathbb{R})$, hence you need $5$ points to recover the coefficients, if you do not know where the center is. Otherwise, $3$ points (such that no two of them are symmetric with respect to the center) are enough, since their mirror images with respect to the center of the ellipse still lie on the ellipse, so having $3$ points and the center is like having $6$ points on the ellipse. Obviously, having two points and the center is not enough, since there are many concentric ellipses that pass through the same two points.

Comment: Why could you not let a=1 and do it with four? Because your equation can be changed to one with a =1 by dividing it by a (and if a is zero, this would be a parabola not an ellipse).

Comment: Oh, i see, you would. But that still leaves five constants for which to solve.