# Ellipse equation from center and point on ellipse

Tags: geometry

Is there a way to get the equation of an ellipse iw we know the center and one point on the ellipse ?

Comment: No, unless you add some other condition. In general, there are infinte ellipses having a given center and passing through a given point.

Comment: No, that does not uniquely determine an ellipse. Take a look at [this example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2F9%2By%5E2%2F4%3D1,+x%5E2%2By%5E2%2F4%3D1).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880258/minimal-number-of-points-to-define-a-rotated-ellipse

Answer (score 2):

A general ellipse has five independent parameters, so you need five conditions to define one. The center and an extra point is far from being enough. Anyway, the center condition absorbs two degrees of freedom at a time.

By translating the given points so that the center moves to the origin, the equation loses its linear terms and the centered conic is

$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+d=0.$$

Then given three other points, the equation is

$$\left|\begin{matrix}x^2&xy&y^2&1\\x_0^2&x_0y_0&y_0^2&1\\x_1^2&x_1y_1&y_1^2&1\\x_2^2&x_2y_2&y_2^2&1\\\end{matrix}\right|=0.$$

If in addition the ellipse is axis parallel, there is no cross term $xy$ and you can do with one point less,

$$\left|\begin{matrix}x^2&y^2&1\\x_0^2&y_0^2&1\\x_1^2&y_1^2&1\\\end{matrix}\right|=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

No. There are infinitely many ellipses with these conditions.

Even if the axes of the ellipse must be parallel to coordinate axes, the equation can't be fully determined.

If the center is $(p,q)$ and the known point is $(u,v)$ we get the equation

$$\frac{(u-p)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(v-q)^2}{b^2}=1$$

This equation has two unknowns (namely, $a$ and $b$) and is not determined, in general.

Comment: + the second point of the ellipse symmetrically associated to the (u, v) in the center of the ellipse   - but it is not enough..